# Returning reference to temporary c++

Tags: c++, reference

```
SongPart mtm::SongStructure::getPart(int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < num_of_parts);
    return song_parts[index];
}

const SongPart& mtm::Song::operator[](int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < song_length);
    return (song_format->getPart(index));
}
```

I get this warning from the returning value in the second function:

> returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]

How to fix this? And I can't change the returning values of each function!

Comment: You *do* need to change getPart to expose a reference if you want to pass it out from SongPart::operator[] by reference.

Comment: `getPart` should probably return a `SongPart const&`

Comment: You have excluded the correct fix. In order to provide a different fix, tell us more about why you can't change the return values of each function.

Answer (score 4):

You get the warning because `getPart` returns a *copy* of `song_parts[index]`. If it returns *reference* to `song_parts[index]`, then your code would be correct.

So you need to change the return type of `getPart` to `SongPart const&`:

```
SongPart const & mtm::SongStructure::getPart(int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < num_of_parts);
    return song_parts[index];
}
```

The `const` is necessary, as the function is a `const` member function.

Why use `assert` in `operator[]` also when you forward the call to `getPart`which does the assert anyway? Just write this:

```
const SongPart& mtm::Song::operator[](int index) const {
    //assert(index >= 0 && index < song_length); not needed!
    return (song_format->getPart(index));
}
```

Avoid extra bound-checks when it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

change the first function to be:

```
const SongPart& mtm::SongStructure::getPart(int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < num_of_parts);
    return song_parts[index];
}
```

the reason is the call to `song_format->getPart(index)` returned by value, thus create a local on the stack of the 2nd function. And if you return a reference to it, after the 2nd function returns, Boom....

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the return type of `getPart()`, then you cannot usefully invoke it. Let's consider how you can access the data without invoking `getPart()`.

Solution 1: Call some *other* function:

```
const SongPart& mtm::SongStructure::getPartReference(int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < num_of_parts);
    return song_parts[index];
}

const SongPart& mtm::Song::operator[](int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < song_length);
    return (song_format->getPartReference(index));
}
```

Solution #2: return `song_parts[index]` directly from `operator[]`:

```
const SongPart& mtm::Song::operator[](int index) const {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < song_length);
    return (song_format->song_parts[index]);
}
```

Comment: What if `song_parts` is `private` (which it should be)? Note that `Song` and `SongStructure` are two different class, and `song_parts` is a member of `SongStructure`.

Comment: Then, in Solution #2, he'll need to add a friend declaration to `SongStructure`, or change it from `private` to `public`.

Comment: both are bad idea, in my opinion.

Comment: Granted, but OP has already eliminated the good idea. All that are left are bad ideas.